# Query to group by for last n number of days

Tags: t-sql

i have a table of employees with empnum,name, age , date of join.

I need to find out count of records for the last 90 days , group by age.
How can a write a query in TSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT age , count(*)  
from table1 
where date >= DATEADD(dd,-90,GETUTCDATE()) 
Group by age
```

Comment: your where condition is wrong

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply filter, followed by group by.

```sql
SELECT age, COUNT(*) as CountOfEmployees
FROM employees
WHERE dateOfJoin < CAST(DATEADD(dd,-90,GETDATE()) AS DATE)
group by age
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be incorrect to save AGE, usually, it is something like DateOfBirth and you calculate the age from there.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, DateOfBirth, getdate()), COUNT(*) as CountOfEmployees
FROM employees
WHERE CAST(DATEADD(dd,-90,GETDATE()) AS DATE) < dateOfJoin 
group by DATEDIFF(year, DateOfBirth, getdate())
```